# Android, color filter only works in preview

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-color

I am trying to get a white oval shape with a gradient stroke, kind of like a colored shadow.

I Need the color to be dynamically changed, so I tried adding a `ColorFilter` to a drawable.

```
        Drawable pulseDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.touch_circle);
        pulseDrawable.setColorFilter(App.userColor, PorterDuff.Mode.LIGHTEN);
        setBackground(pulseDrawable);
```

This is what I get in the preview toolbar

[image]

But when I run the app I get this,(poorly drawn using paint) :

[image]

The circle is fine, but instead of color adding the glow/shadow. It filled all the rest of the view with blue color.

I tried maing the layertype software, but that didn't work.

So why is the preview rendering fine, while running the app doesn't? Is there a way I could fix this? I'm also open for other solutions like drawing the shape programmatically without a bitmap

Comment: can be the difference in API version. Which Android version is on your phone?

Comment: Change the filter mode to `PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN`

Comment: @TusharGogna Android 5.1 Using build tools 26.0.1

Comment: @AjilO. SRC_IN gives me a blue circle, I just want the blue "shadow". So Lighten will give me that cause white + anything = white

Comment: Did you run it after changing the mode to SCR_IN? I do not trust the output on the preview...

Comment: @AjilO. yes I did

Comment: Can you post code for your drawable? I'd like to try it out myself

Comment: @AjilO. The drawable is a png, no code. The only code is the color filter. http://imgur.com/a/C27LN

Comment: @vlatkozelka Let me know if my answer works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this was what you intended. I have created a drawable. You can play with the values till you get what works for you.

shadow.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <size
                android:width="100dp"
                android:height="100dp"/>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#eee"
                android:endColor="#0FFF"
                android:gradientRadius="45%"
                android:type="radial"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:left="22dp"
        android:bottom="22dp"
        android:top="22dp"
        android:right="22dp">
        <shape
            android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#FFF"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Code to change the color at runtime

```
imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
Drawable bg = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.shadow);
int color = ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.colorAccent);
bg.setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
imgView.setBackground(bg);
```

And here is the code for the imageView

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgView"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:src="@drawable/shadow"/>
```